# Dynamic Array of Class objects

Tags: arrays, class, dynamic, unityscript

I have created a class in Javascript and I want to create a dynamic array containing items of this class.

I am not allowed to use `push` for my custom array.

That's what I've tried so far:

```
//InvItem is my class!
var items : InvItem[] = new InvItem[itemCount];
```

but this isn't dynamic at all.

How can I delete (pop) or insert (push) any item into or out of the array dynamically?

Can I use something like malloc for C?

Comment: that's not javascript...

Comment: It is javascript but I'm not sure which version of it. I'm using it inside Unity3d.

Comment: Ah, that's [unityscript](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript)

Comment: As for push, the compiler complains: `'push' is not a member of 'InvItem[]'.` @bfavaretto thanks for the link.